# Color a specific bar in histogram using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, plotly

I have a histogram (matplotlib or plotly) and want to color a specific bar, witch has value N in the bar range (for example if N=131 the colored bar must be 130-132). How can i do that?

Answer (score 10):

When calling `plt.hist()`, it will return three things. Firstly an array holding the value in each bin. Secondly the values for each of the bins, and lastly an array of `patches`. These let you modify each bar individually. So all you need to do is determine which bin is for the range `130-132` and then modify the colour, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values =  np.random.randint(51, 140, 1000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(values, bins=np.arange(50, 140, 2), align='left', color='g')
patches[40].set_fc('r')
plt.show()
```

Would display something like:

[image: example showing one red bar]

Here the 41st patch corresponds to the range `130-132` as the bins I have chosen start at `50` and go up to `140` in steps of 2. So there will be `45` bins in total. If you `print bins` you would see that index `40` is the one you want:

```
[ 50  52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66  68  70  72  74  76  78  80  82  84
  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100 102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120
 122 124 126 128 130 132 134 136 138]
```